# WEB.XML error-page in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2, error-handling

*I'm using JSF2 and Glassfish 3.0.*

I have a very simple application and I'm trying to set up some default error pages for `404` and `500` error.

This is the `WEB.XML` section:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>404</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>500</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Even though error.xhtml exists, In the browser I still get the standard `HTTP Status 404 -` warning.

Answer (score 13):

The `<exception-type>` should point to the full qualified name of a subclass of [`java.lang.Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). E.g.

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

But what you've there are just [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). You should be using `<error-code>` instead.

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

By the way, I wouldn't let 404 and 500 point to the same error page. A 404 is a "page not found" which is usually client's own mistake, not server's mistake. Getting a general error page instead of a "page not found" would then be very confusing.