# Why do I get an unexpected TypeConversion error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a site in Primefaces 10. There is a subsite fur listing the results. I want to have a selectManyCheckbox filled with a list of enums, which results in an array of those enums. On one subsite it works and on another I do almost the same thing (other enum) and I get the conversion error when I send the form.
My xhtml looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="../layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="header">
        <div id="header">
            Dashboard
        </div>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="main">
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-chart {
                margin-bottom: 50px;
            }
        </style>
        <h:form id="dashboardForm">
            <p:messages id="dashboardErrMsg" globalOnly="true"/>

            <p:selectManyCheckbox id="abfSelector" value="#{dashboardHandler.selectedAbfragen}" layout="grid" columns="3" styleClass="grid-checkbox">
                <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardHandler.abfragen}" var="abfrage" itemLabel="#{abfrage.name}" itemValue="#{abfrage}"/>
            </p:selectManyCheckbox>
            
            <p:commandButton id="showButton" value="Anzeigen" icon="pi pi-search" action="#{dashboardHandler.anzeigen}"/>
    
            <div class="card">
                <p:lineChart model="#{dashboardHandler.lineModel}" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"/>
            </div>
    
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

and the bean looks like this:

```java
@Named("dashboardHandler")
@ViewScoped
public class DashboardHandler implements Serializable {

    private List<Abfrage> abfragen = new ArrayList<>();
    private Abfrage[] selectedAbfragen;
    
    private LineChartModel lineModel;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        abfragen = UcmdbAbfTableHandler.getAbfragenBySystem(ReferenceSystem.UCMDB);
        createLineModel();
    }

    public void anzeigen() {
    //do some search
    }

    public List<Abfrage> getAbfragen() { return abfragen; }
    public LineChartModel getLineModel() { return lineModel; }
    public Abfrage[] getSelectedAbfragen() { return selectedAbfragen; }

    public void setAbfragen(List<Abfrage> abfragen) { this.abfragen = abfragen; }
    public void setLineModel(LineChartModel lineModel) { this.lineModel = lineModel; }
    public void setSelectedAbfragen(Abfrage[] selectedAbfragen) { this.selectedAbfragen = selectedAbfragen; }
}
```

I can't see my error why there is a type conversion error. I've tried changing the Abfrage-Array to a List then I'm getting a list with Strings of the classname of abfrage like when I make an abfrage.toString().

I also don't understand why my messages isn't triggered. I always get the error in my Logfile with unhandeled facesmessage. So I think I'm doing something wrong here too.

Answer (score 1):

When the selectItems are Enums, the issue is answered here: [Use enum in h:selectManyCheckbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822058/use-enum-in-hselectmanycheckbox).

When the selectItems are regular POJOs, you need to include a specific faces converter. There are several answers on StackOverflow for converters, such as this one: [How create a custom converter in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001079/how-create-a-custom-converter-in-jsf-2). Omnifaces, a JSF utility library, includes a `SelectItemsConverter` that can often be used off-the-shelf, without additional coding.

The `messages` issue is because the messages tag isn't being ajax updated from the commandButton, or you can use `p:autoUpdate` on the messages tag (see [PF Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml)). Note that `messages` will not capture system errors like conversion errors as you describe. For that you need to include error pages in the web.xml file (e.g. see [WEB.XML error-page in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296613/web-xml-error-page-in-jsf-2-0)). You should also capture and display ajax errors. (See [PrimeFaces error handling](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/errorhandling)). And ensure that `ProjectStages` context parameter is set to something other than Production - e.g. Development.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but my I have mistaken Abfrage for an enum, but it is a normal class instead. I will make a normal HashMap and work with this. But the conversion error is still not showing.

Comment: In that case you need to include a faces converter. I will update my answer accordingly.